# Writing dictionary contents in a file

Tags: iphone

What is the easiest way to write content of a dictionary into a file. Sample code will be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write to a plist file. That would be the easiest (to read back and write to)

Use the NSDictionary method **writeToFile:atomically:** to write to a plist and **initWithContentsOfFile:** to populate the dictionary with the plist's contents.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the NSCoding protocol: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i